# RestController Integration Tests Junit5 Error

Tags: spring-boot, integration-testing, junit5

I am development a integration tests for a RestController

```
@RestController
public class MyController {

    //fields
    private ModelMapper mapper;

    private MyService myService;

    //constructor
    public MyController(ModelMapper mapper, Myservice myService) {
        this.mapper = mapper;
        this.myService = myService;
    }

    @GetMapping(value = "/test", produces = "application/json")
    public ResponseEntity<Page<Dto>> retrieveAll(pageNumber, pageSize)
    .....
```

and my test classes implementation

```
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@WebMvcTest(MyController.class)
class MyControllerIntegrationTest {
    
     @Autowired
     MockMvc mockMvc;
    
     @MockBean
     MyService myService;
    
     @MockBean
     ModelMapper modelMapper;
    
    
     @Test
     void test() throws Exception{

         ObjFactory objFactory = new ObjFactory();

         Mockito.when(myService.retrieveAll(1,20)).thenReturn(objFactory.createRandomList());
    
         mockMvc.perform(MockMvcRequestBuilders.get("/test"))
                  .andExpect(MockMvcResultMatchers.status().isOk());
    
    
        }

    }
```

and in my Mockito is returning a array with 2 model/entity elements.

i am getting this error

```
org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is java.lang.NullPointerException
     
    ...
    
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach
at java.base/java.util.ArrayList.forEach
        
   Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
                at com.testing.john.controller.myController.retrieveAll(MyController.java:48)
                at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
                at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
                at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
                at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:566)
```

What may be the problem?

This endpoint via http client(Postman) give me 200 and give me a Page.

I am testing some strategies but doesn't works.

Thanks

Comment: can you show this line 48 in `MyController.java`

Comment: I found the error on that line, I had a .stream and a map inside and it returned the error.